# Make certain PDF Fields uneditable in Apache PDFBox

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, pdfbox

I am using Apache PDFBox for a Rest Endpoint of a Java Spring Application to fill out a Template PDF that is stored on the Webserver. After PDFBox filled the PDF using Acroform features I would like to make some Textfields/Checkboxes/Dropdowns locked/uneditable. Some other Fields should still be editable after the User downloads it.

What I tried already: Google search. Went through the Apache PDFBox doc's a bit. Searched StackOverflow for similar existing Questions.

Answer (score 0):

Fields have a 'setReadOnly' method that can be used for that.